Azure SignalR Service Not Working as a WebSocket Connection
I have an ASP.NET Core application that provides a SignalR hub for real-time notifications. I used the SignalR hub as a WebSocket endpoint with a self-hosted SignalR server. Using the WebSocket package in my Flutter web application, I could connect to the hub, receive notifications, and even test the connection using Postman.
Recently, I migrated from the self-hosted SignalR setup to Azure SignalR Service. Now, my Flutter web app and Postman can no longer connect to the same endpoint, wss://example.com/chat-hub. The connection fails during the handshake, and I cannot even establish a WebSocket connection using Postman.
I have followed this tutorial to migrate from self-hosted SignalR to Azure SignalR service

Hi Yasir Arefin Tusher, please try to enable signalr logging feature. And please also enable the azure signalr live tracing  in azure portal.. Waiting for your update.

@JasonPan Thanks for your kind response. I will get back very soon.

Hi Yasir Arefin Tusher, please hide your sensitive information in your logs, it can protect your data safely.

@Yasir Arefin Tusher  Flutter client for SignalR (ASP.NET Core). You can find it at Pub/ signalR Client

@Sampath This package works on only mobile, not Flutter Web. That's why I am using websocket channel to establish websocket connection
